# Search for AD Extension Attributes in use

Tags: powershell, active-directory

A lot of scripts out there show how you can pull extension attributes in AD, but what if you don't know what you have populated for extension attributes? Sure, you could just do a simple export and some Excel filtering to figure that out, but that takes too much time, I'd rather have PowerShell do the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created this simple script to search through extensionAttribute 1-15 and return all relevant information if they're in use. The export in the code below requires the ImportExcel module from PowerShell Gallery, or you can simply replace it with Export-CSV.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel

```
$i = 0
$x = $null
$noteproperty = @()
$Excelobject = @()
for ($i = 1; $i -le 15; $i++) {
    "extensionAttribute$i"
    $x = Get-ADObject -Filter "extensionAttribute$i -ne `"*`"" -Properties * | Select-Object DistinguishedName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, extensionAttribute$i
    if ($x) {
        $noteproperty += "extensionAttribute$i"
        $Excelobject += $x
    }
}
$noteproperty | ForEach-Object { $Excelobject[0] | Add-Member -Name $_ -Value $null -MemberType NoteProperty -ErrorAction Ignore }
$Excelobject | Export-Excel -Path $home\Desktop\ExtensionAttributes.xlsx
```